# Salesforce.com and database.com integration

Tags: salesforce

We are designing a project in which we plan to use 20 SFDC users (managers) and more than 100 database.com light users (salesmen). The idea is that the SDFC users will use the site to see reports and so on, while the others will use our mobile software which relies on API calls to create orders and similar.

I never used database.com before and I am quite a newbie with force.com. I just created a db.com account but I have no idea on how I can connect the two systems together. I want the both types of users to access to the same records, so if a salesman creates an order the manager can see this order in the reports and the online tools. How can achieve that? I there any limitation I should be aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow users almost certainly do not have the necessary knowledge to act as a substitute for the business-to-business departments of these companies. You would be better served by contacting them.

Comment: @ninjagecko I contacted their support and they could not help me as they didn't even know what I was talking about :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if these proprietary websites have a public API.

The only way you can interface with them is through an API, or via really hackish script which simulate a web browser. Thus if they don't have a public API, you should call the appropriate department on their Contact Us page.

Comment: I contacted them and no luck. They have an API, the thing is both systems offer cloud database storage but I am not sure wether I can "merge" both or access the same data in both of them.

I saw some questions about salesforce here so I decided to try, but as you said most users here are not familiar with those systems.